# operation not allowed when object is closed "SQL connection giving error with VBA"

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

I am facing an issue while running a long SQL query with VBA, but when I run a simple one-line select query it works fine BUT

when I run the below complex query it fails, also I'd like to input some values from a defined range/cell into sql query like I would like to input L1100 as timezone from cell A2, what format should i use,  any suggestions on this would be much appreciated

```vb
Public DBConn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub createconn()

Dim UserId, Password As String
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Server = "XXXX"
UserId = "XXXXX"
Password = "XXXX"
With DBConn
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;" & _
    "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
    "SERVER=" & Server & ";" & _
    "UID=" & UserId & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
End With

End Sub

Sub Stalecheck()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim DBresults As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlquery As String, wsData As Worksheet, Datasht As Worksheet
Dim elr As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Set DBresults = New ADODB.Recordset


Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Datasht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
'wsData.Range("U5:Y5", Range("U5").End(xlDown)).Clear
Datasht.Cells.ClearContents
'lRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

'Worksheets("UPDATER").Range("N2", "N" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("UPDATER").Range("V5")
'Mainsheet.Range("B7:B15").ClearContents
If wsData.Range("B3").Value <> "" Then


    Call createconn
    
    'sqlquery = "select * from instrument_equity"

    
  sqlquery = "select i.name, i.pkey, nvl(i.enddate,round((i.periodyears * 365.25),0) + vyc.asof) maturity," & vbNewLine & _
"nvl(i.period,i.enddate) period, vyc.asof, vyc.timezone, vyc.snaptime, vyc.rowkey, nvl(nvl(pfx.price, p.rate*100),vp.rate) rate," & vbNewLine & _
"nvl(nvl(pfx.updatetime, p.snaptime),vp.updatetime) updatetime, vms.symbol source" & vbNewLine & _
"from val_yield_curves vyc" & vbNewLine & _
"JOIN val_yc_def_elements el ON el.pkey=valuations_yieldcurves.getCurveDefinitionKey(vyc.asof, vyc.object_id)" & vbNewLine & _
"JOIN instruments i on i.pkey = el.instrument" & vbNewLine & _
"LEFT JOIN (SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate*100 rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_interestrates" & vbNewLine & _
"UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate*100, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_basisswaps" & vbNewLine & _
"UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate*100, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_oisrates" & vbNewLine & _
"UNION SELECT asof, curve, instrument, rate, quality, source, updatetime, bid, ask FROM val_prices_fx)" & vbNewLine & _
"vp ON i.pkey = vp.instrument" & vbNewLine & _
"and vp.asof=vyc.asof" & vbNewLine & _
"and vp.curve=vyc.rowkey" & vbNewLine & _
"LEFT JOIN prices_fixings p ON p.instrument = i.pkey and p.asof = vyc.asof" & vbNewLine & _
"LEFT JOIN val_prices_fxfixings pfx ON pfx.instrument = i.pkey" & vbNewLine & _
"and pfx.asof = vyc.asof" & vbNewLine & _
"and pfx.timezone = vyc.timezone" & vbNewLine & _
"LEFT JOIN val_mds_sources vms ON vms.pkey = vp.source" & vbNewLine & _
"WHERE vyc.asof = '11Jul20'" & vbNewLine & _
"and vyc.timezone = 'L1000'" & vbNewLine & _
"and vyc.object_id like 'CAD_IRIndex_3M'" & vbNewLine & _
"and i.type <> 'Future'" & vbNewLine & _
"ORDER BY vyc.object_id, i.type desc, el.type, i.ccy, i.ccy2, nvl(i.periodyears, nvl((i.enddate-trunc(sysdate))/365,0)), vyc.snaptime DESC"





    'sqlquery = Left(sqlquery, Len(sqlquery) - 1) & ")"
    DBresults.Open sqlquery, DBConn, adOpenDynamic
    If Not DBresults.EOF Then Datasht.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset DBresults
        
    
    End If


Set DBresults = Nothing
Call close_conn
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub



Sub close_conn()

DBConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide more details about " it fails" !

Comment: does your complex adhoc-generated sql execute in oracle-tools (sqlplus/sqldeveloper) at all? from first look this query cries for a view-creation in oracle ... way to complex for adhoc. or create a procedure producing the result-set

Comment: it gives unspecified error while executing the below line DBresults.Open sqlquery, DBConn, adOpenDynamic

Comment: and when i use debug.print sqlquery and tru to run it in golden 6 (oracle software) it runs fine

Comment: How long does it takes to execute in golden 6? The ODBC driver you're using has a timeout.

Comment: that query takes 5 secs to execute in golden 6 environment, I think the issue is not with the code, it's with the indentation of query because when I run a simple query " select * from a table" the code works fine.